# Prove that for a random variable $X$, there exists a value of $x$, such that $x \geq E(X)$ and $p(x)>0$ (Nielsen and Chuang)?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Here $p(x)$ is the probability that $X=x$ and $E(X)$ is the expectation.
I have limited my self to the random variable $X$ taking discrete values. So, in this case, $$ E(X)= \sum_i p(x_i)x_i.$$ I am able to prove this if the set of values $\{x_i\}$ with non zero probability that $X$ can take, is a finite set. In that case there $\exists \tilde{X} \in {x_i}$ such that $\tilde{X} \geq \{x_i\}$. Combining this with $$\sum_i p(x_i)=1. $$ we have $$ E(X)= \sum_i p(x_i)x_i \leq \sum_i p(x_i)\tilde{X} =\tilde{X}.$$ Hence, proved. But, what if the set of values $\{x_i\}$ with non zero probability that $X$ can take is infinite (but countable). In this case, even if the set is bounded (say the least upper bound is $\tilde{X}$), how would I be able to say if $p(\tilde{X})>0$. Is there another approach to this problem which includes all cases (including continous values)?

Comment: The statement is not true for the continuous case. For example, for the random variable $X(x)=x$ defined on $[0,1]$ with the uniform probability, then the probability that $X=x$ is zero for every $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\{i: x_i <EX\}$ and $B=\{i: x_i \geq EX\}$. Then $EX=\sum_{i \in A} x_ip(x_i)+\sum_{i \in B} x_ip(x_i)$. If $p(x_i)>0$ for some $i\in B$ then the assertion  is proved. Suppose there is, no such $i$. Then we get $EX=\sum_{i \in A} x_ip(x_i)$. But this last sum is clearly $< (EX) (\sum p(x_i))=EX(1)=EX$. So we get the contradiction $EX<EX$.